# Numpy throws an IndexError although indices seem to be integers for me

Tags: python, numpy

Given a weighted directed graph and one specific node defined as a "destination", I'm trying to find links that are the first links on the shortest path from each node to the destination. To achieve this goal, I first tried the following code.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np


def choose_nextlink(graph, current_node, destination):
    path_shortest = nx.shortest_path(graph, source=current_node, target=destination)
    return path_shortest[0:2]


def main():
    nodes = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
    destinations = np.array([4])
    edges = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [2, 3], [3, 4]])
    weights = np.array([1, 10, 2, 3])

    G = nx.DiGraph()
    G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
    G.add_weighted_edges_from(np.hstack([edges, np.array([weights]).transpose()]))

    links_next = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: choose_nextlink(G, current_node=np.setdiff1d(nodes, destinations)[i], destination=4)[j], (np.setdiff1d(nodes, destinations).shape[0], 2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the graph defined above, shortest paths from nodes 1, 2, and 3 to node 4 are

- 1 to 4: 1–2–3–4
- 2 to 4: 2–3–4
- 3 to 4: 3–4,

so I'd like `links_next` to be

```
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4]])
```

However, running this script by `python3 test.py` issues an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 20, in main
    links_next = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: choose_nextlink(G, current_node=np.setdiff1d(nodes, destinations)[i], destination=4)[j], (np.setdiff1d(nodes, destinations).shape[0], 2))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 2132, in fromfunction
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 20, in <lambda>
    links_next = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: choose_nextlink(G, current_node=np.setdiff1d(nodes, destinations)[i], destination=4)[j], (np.setdiff1d(nodes, destinations).shape[0], 2))
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

After some googling with the raised error, It seems [these changes](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.12.0-notes.rst#deprecationwarning-to-error) introduced in v1.12.0 relevant, but I haven't found a solution yet. I think all the indices in line 20 (variables `i` and `j` and a numeric `0`) are of integer type.

Of course I can do the same task using `for` loop, but I'd like to avoid that approach as my actual data set is large. Where am I doing wrong with the code above?